# Exchange 2007 - mailbox limits doesn't work

Tags: exchange-2007, mailbox

A mailbox was migrated from Exchange 2003 to 2007. The mailbox limits (4.0gb, 4.2gb, 4,4gb) were kept as they we're over default size. The user cannot send mails though the size is under the limit (~3.7gb). I've tried to set even higher limits with no succes (did wait for at least 2 hours).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting your limits? In the user, or the at the storage group?

Comment: We set individual limits (user), and have similar mailbox limits working fine.

Comment: Is the user sending email via Outlook (are they using Cached Exchange Mode) or OWA? Does the issue repeat using OWA?  Also, try restarting the IS service if you haven't already (your users will be offline for a few minutes though).

Comment: Is the Public Store reached its limit?  And you can confirm the regkey is successfully set to the size you want it to be?

Comment: USACASD - I believe you're on to something. He sends using Outlook in cached mode, but is able to send through OWA! I won't be able to test IIS reset before earliest tomorrow monday. Followup question: resetting IIS will only affect OWA users right? Will they be logged out as well?
It could maybe be fixed by just setting up his acount on Outlook again? (thus deleting .OST file and creating a new one)

IrqJD - I will be able to check this tomorrow, but I assume we would have more users with the same problem if this was the case.

Comment: Did you find resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're hitting different type of limit then mailbox size: http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/exchange-2007-message-size-limits.html

Please check the tutorial to set/check other limits and see if that might be the case. Also having an error from the mail that returned would be great.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this issue isn't related to other limits. Test mails were within the limits when I tested from his Outlook. Now that you mention it, I did not find the automated warning/error mail that he should have received. When he sends he gets the mailbox cleanup wizard, which actually made things even worse, because he had setup auto-archive to delete expired messages, and thus lost some mails. Could this actually be an Outlook error rather than an Exchange limit/error?

Comment: I don't think Outlook has limits that small.

Comment: If Outlook is the problem I wouldn't suspect a limit problem. Rather maybe some kind of sync. problem after the migration perhaps. Or just a bug of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

What do your log files and error messages say?  Are you sure it's a mailbox limit issue?  Check EMS to confirm the storage quotas ( http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/09/20/428965.aspx ).

Also see:
Mailbox Size Limits Are Not Enforced in a Reasonable Period of Time
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684892%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not certain it's a limit issue. I did check the mailbox limits through EMS, and they were correct meaning they were set to the limits stated in my first post (actually higher now for testing purposes). I'm aware of the default 2 hours for cached mailbox information to be refreshed.

I did not find any log entries concerning the specific mailbox in the event viewer. Which other logs would I need to check?